# Is it possible to know `XSUB` was called using `&sub`

Tags: perl, perl-xs, perlapi

When `PP` sub is called the `CX` for this sub is created.
By accessing this context by `CxHASARGS(CX_CUR())` we can check this sub `hasargs` or not.

But for the `XSUB` context is not created, so we can not use this trick.

Is is possible to know `XSUB` was called using `&sub` or not?

**UPD**
Looking at sources at `pp_entersub` when `cv` is `XSUB`. We can see how code handle `hasargs`. It access `PL_op->op_flags & OPf_STACKED` then a bit later call the target `XSUB`:

```
if( PL_op->op_flags & OPf_STACKED ...
...
CvXSUB(cv)(aTHX_ cv);
```

**Will it be OK if I in my `XSUB` I do same check of `PL_op->op_flags & OPf_STACKED`?**